# returning a pointer and changing what it points to

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to return a pointer and change what it points to but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm doing it like this:

```
class someClass
{
    public:
        int *& foo();
    private:
        int * ptr = 5;
};

int *& someClass::foo()
{
    return ptr;
}
int main()
{
    int * ptrTwo = foo();
    ptrTwo = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

I expected this to change ptr to NULL. What happened was ptr was unaffected and only ptrTwo was changed to NULL.

Comment: What is `ptr` and where is it declared or defined? Speaking about it, where is the definition of `className`?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. What are you _actually_  trying to achieve?

Comment: It's the same situation as `int x = 123; int& f() { return x; } /*...*/ int y = f(); y = 0;`, where `x` is unchanged. There is nothing special about pointers.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Didn't I show what I wanted to achieve? I have a int pointer data member that is part of a class and I want to return it through a function and change what it points to, to NULL.

Comment: @Dante No, you didn't.

Comment: @NickyC Okay, I was trying to make sure there wasn't a bunch of code in the way that didn't need to be read. What else should I have added to make it more clear?

Comment: @Dante there is not enough information in your question and I'm not the only one who thinks so. You should show a [mcve] and explain what you expect to happen and what actually happens.

Comment: Just make an example, like the one above but with a few extra lines so that it compiles and produces the error. No need to include all your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
#include <cstdio>

class className
{
public:
  int *ptr = (int*)1;
  int *& foo();
};

int *& className::foo()
{
  return ptr;
}

int main()
{
  className instance;

  int *& ptrTwo = instance.foo();
    // ^
    // |---- watch the &
    //
  printf("ptrTwo = %p\n", ptrTwo);

  ptrTwo = NUL     // this actually sets instance.ptr to NULL

  printf("instance.ptr = %p\n", (void*)instance.ptr);
}
```

BTW the code above is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

The output will be something like this:

```
ptrTwo = 00000001
instance.ptr = 00000000
```

or

```
ptrTwo = 0x1
instance.ptr = (nil)
```

depending on your platform.

[Live demonstration](https://www.ideone.com/8wmXLQ)

Answer (score -3):

The problem here is you are returning a reference to the local pointer.

You should either change it to static:

```
static int ptr=&something;
```

...then return it.

Or you should return the reference of an globally declared pointer.

Comment: Thanks for your first contribution to StackOverflow! Be sure to look at Michael Walz's answer. He provided a great example of how to fully and clearly answer a question. We look forward to your future contributions.